Subprocess error when installing fastai with Python
I've been trying to install fastai to Python 3.11.8 so I could access fastai.vision.all (my code editor is Visual Studio Code) However, after using "python -m pip install fastai", I recieved an subprocess.CalledProcessError, stating "This error originates from a subprocess, and it's likely not a problem with pip.
Here's the full error message I got from the terminal:

error: subprocess-exited-with-error



  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.

  │ exit code: 1

  ╰─> [55 lines of output]

      The Meson build system

      Version: 0.62.2

      Source dir: C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lfh_uajv\scipy_0c2595c1abca45c9840a4fe284f06c6a

      Build dir: C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lfh_uajv\scipy_0c2595c1abca45c9840a4fe284f06c6a\.mesonpy-qppxu250\build

      Build type: native build

      Project name: SciPy

      Project version: 1.9.1

      WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output



      ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]

      The following exception(s) were encountered:

      Running "icl " gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      Running "cl /?" gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      Running "cc --version" gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      Running "gcc --version" gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      Running "clang --version" gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      Running "clang-cl /?" gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      Running "pgcc --version" gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"



      A full log can be found at C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lfh_uajv\scipy_0c2595c1abca45c9840a4fe284f06c6a\.mesonpy-qppxu250\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt

      + meson setup --native-file=C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lfh_uajv\scipy_0c2595c1abca45c9840a4fe284f06c6a\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2 --prefix=C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lfh_uajv\scipy_0c2595c1abca45c9840a4fe284f06c6a C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lfh_uajv\scipy_0c2595c1abca45c9840a4fe284f06c6a\.mesonpy-qppxu250\build

      Traceback (most recent call last):

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>

          main()

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main

          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])

                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel

          return hook(config_settings)

                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zzmgqcft\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 969, in get_requires_for_build_wheel

          with _project(config_settings) as project:

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__

          return next(self.gen)

                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zzmgqcft\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 948, in _project

          with Project.with_temp_working_dir(

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__

          return next(self.gen)

                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zzmgqcft\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 777, in with_temp_working_dir

          yield cls(source_dir, tmpdir, build_dir)

                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zzmgqcft\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 682, in __init__

          self._configure(reconfigure=bool(build_dir) and not native_file_mismatch)

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zzmgqcft\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 713, in _configure

          self._meson(

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zzmgqcft\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 696, in _meson

          return self._proc('meson', *args)

                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zzmgqcft\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 691, in _proc

          subprocess.check_call(list(args))

        File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call

          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)

      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['meson', 'setup', '--native-file=C:\\Users\\UserPC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lfh_uajv\\scipy_0c2595c1abca45c9840a4fe284f06c6a\\.mesonpy-native-file.ini', '-Ddebug=false', '-Doptimization=2', '--prefix=C:\\Users\\UserPC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311', 'C:\\Users\\UserPC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lfh_uajv\\scipy_0c2595c1abca45c9840a4fe284f06c6a', 'C:\\Users\\UserPC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lfh_uajv\\scipy_0c2595c1abca45c9840a4fe284f06c6a\\.mesonpy-qppxu250\\build']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

      [end of output]



  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: subprocess-exited-with-error



× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.

│ exit code: 1

╰─> See above for output.



note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


I've tried to upgrade pip as well as installing both setuptools wheel and scipy, but none have worked. I'm not sure if it's because of the version of fastai and scipy not being complatible with the version of Python. Any advice would be appreciated.

The exception seems to be generated by the mesonpy package , which is a wrapper around the meson build system. To install fastai from source, you need a working C compiler such as gcc, clang, cl(comes with C/C++ SDK of Visual Studio). Install any of these compilers and have them added to the PATH environment variable.

I see, thanks. Any sources where I can install a good C compiler? Also, another workaround I found was to install old versions between Typer and Fastai that are compatible with each other, Scipy and Python 3.11.8 (had to install them in a new enviroment made through Anaconda Prompt) It worked well enough but not sure if that's a better alternative.

You can a C compiler from various sources. Installing MinGW(which is a development environment) will install gcc. Installing C/C++ SDK on Visual Studio is another solution.  Git bash for windows also includes a version of gcc.

This meson error is complaining that it can't build SciPy from source. There are a few ways you can solve this problem.
Use pre-compiled binaries
The simplest way would be to use pre-compiled binaries. Reading the list of released builds on PyPi, the first SciPy version to have a pre-compiled wheel compatible with Python 3.11 is SciPy 1.10.1. You could also use the latest version of SciPy, 1.14.1, which is also compatible with Python 3.11.
Compile your own
If you are using a platform which does not have pre-compiled binaries, you can work around this by compiling your own. I recommend consulting the Building from Source documentation. It explains how to install a compiler which is known to work with SciPy.

Thanks, and what about Fastai? Is there is there a version that's comatible with both Python 3.11.8 and SciPy (1.10.1-1.14.1)?

Forgot to mention that for fastai, I'm planning on using fastao.vision.all. Not sure which version has that import.

@HorizonCrosser128 It looks like FastAI is a pure Python package, so it wouldn't need to be compiled for each Python version. I looked at FastAI's dependencies, and they don't declare a minimum required version of SciPy, so I would assume that any version would work.
